# how to see users profile by searching him and by clicking on its link

Tags: php, html, mysql, profile

here i created a link of the customer.

```
<a name="id" href="https://127.0.0.1/new taxicab/account/driver/profile/index.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['fullname']; ?></a>
```

and the index.php is

```
    <?php $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "black9024!@","new_taxicab");
$id = ($_GET['id']);
if (empty($_GET['id'])){
    header("location:cheat.php");
    die();
    $sql = "select * from driver where id = '$id'";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
    while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}
    echo $rws['fullname'];?>
    <?php echo $rws['fullname'];

  }
?>
```

but it can't work i know it wrong but what's write please give me some suggestion.

Comment: does your id field is `string` ?

Comment: No my html above id in sot a string it come fro directly database

Comment: if so then in your inde.php file you  should have `id = $id` (query), and you have not specified what is issue with current code

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop the echo $rws['fullname'] is outside of the while's curly braces.  Try:

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "black9024!@","new_taxicab");

$id = ($_GET['id']);

if (empty($_GET['id'])){

 header("location:cheat.php");
die();
}

$sql = "select * from driver where id = '$id'";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));

while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo $rws['fullname'];   <-- Here

};

?>
```

Comment: I would test a few things on the index.php page.  Is the id variable getting populated from the $_GET?  Is the $result being populated after the query.  Try print_r($result) and see if you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "black9024!@","new_taxicab");

    if (empty($_GET['id'])){

         header("location:cheat.php");
         die();
    }

    $sql = "select * from driver where id = '$_GET[‘id’]'";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));

    while($rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $rws;

    };

 ?>
```

May have to change single quotes I typed this from my phone

@joseph_J your answer looks like it will work but do you need to echo out $rws itself?

From what I can see your not returning the data as an array with the items Id and full name?`$data[‘id’]` where does this come from?